# Duality principle in boolean algebra

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

All the definitions I came across so far stated, that if a statement is true, then also its dual statement is true and this dual statement is obtained by changing `+` for `.`, `0` for `1` and vice versa.

However when I say `1+1`, whose dual statement according to the above is `0.0`, I get opposite results, that is:

```
1 + 1 = 1
0 . 0 = 0
```

How should I understand this duality principle ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

"$1 + 1 = 1$" is a *statement* (a boolean statement, in fact), and indeed, $1 + 1 = 1$ happens to be a true statement.

Likewise, the entire statement "$0 \cdot 0 = 0$" is a *true statement*, since $0 \cdot 0$ *correctly* evaluates to false: and this is exactly what "$0 \cdot 0 = 0$" asserts, so it is a correct (true) statement about the falsity of $0 \cdot 0$.

The duality principle ensures that "if we exchange **every** symbol by its dual in a formula, we get the **dual** result".

- Everywhere we see 1, change to 0.
- Everywhere we see 0, change to 1.
- Similarly, + to $\cdot$, and $\cdot$ to +.

---

More examples:

(a) `0 . 1 = 0`: is a true statement asserting that "false and true evaluates to false"

(b) `1 + 0 = 1`: is the dual of (a): it is a true statement asserting that "true or false evaluates true."

---

(c) `1 . 1 = 1`: it is a true statement asserting that "true and true evaluates to true".

(d) `0 + 0 = 0`: (d) is the dual of (c): it is a true statement asserting, correctly, that "false or false evaluates to false".

Comment: Ok, so I think I am slowly starting to get it, but I still have difficulties with the last sentence. The dual symbols are `1` and `0` and `+` and `.`, right ? And the dual result means, that if the original result was `1`, the dual result will be `0`. Is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The "result" changes, but the truth value of the entire statement remains true.

Comment: ok, thanks very much, I think it is clear now

Comment: Good: I can understand the confusion!

Comment: @amWhy: Very nicely formatted answer and answer! +1

Comment: I have been late here. sorry.

Comment: Is duality principle applicable only when there is equality ?

Answer (score 4):

The statement is the full equation, including the = sign. `1+1` is neither true nor false: it takes the value `1`, but it is not actually saying anything. Analogously, the expression "Tom has a cat" is neither true nor false (without specifying who Tom is) - it is an expression which could be true or false, depending on who we mean when we say "Tom".

On the other hand, the statement `1+1=0` is a false. Analogously, the statement "If Tom has a cat then Tom has no cats" is false, no matter who we mean when we say "Tom".

In this case, `1+1=1` is the true statement. Its dual is `0.0=0`, which is also a true statement.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I am no mathematician, so I need to have things explained in layman terms. So from your answer I understood that `1+1` is not a statement, so it makes no sense to compare its value to `0.0` and to talk about duality. On the other hand `1+1=1` and `0.0=0` are two true statements, so the duality principle is valid. Is this the correct understanding ?

Comment: `1 + 1` is indeed true, as a boolean statement, as the truth values are given [as true = `1`], and `+` is defined as the boolean "or", so "true or true" has a truth value, and that happens to be true, just as `0.0` reads "false and false" which is false, so "false and false = false" is, as a whole, a true boolean statement.

Comment: An expression has a value, `1` or `0`, but it is not a statement. As your question demonstrates, the duality principle only applies to statements, that is, things which contain an `=` sign. Perhaps it helps to think about `2+2` using normal addition. This clearly evaluates to `4`, but we have no notion of whether it's true or not. However, `2+2=4` is clearly true.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I think I was just misunderstanding what you wrote: and the case here is a bit more complicated than addiction of integers, because here $1$ is identically true, and $0$ is identically false.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is not `1+1` but rather `1+1=1`.

What the duality principle says is that "if you exchange every symbol by its dual in a formula you get the dual result".

Answer (score 1):

The difference between an expression and a statement is that statement is like an equation and expression is like variable.

"Duality of a statement is true" - What this means is that when you equate the dual of both the expressions in LHS and RHS of a statement(equation), the statement still makes sense.

Observe that in your example both 1+1 = 1   &   0.0 = 0 ,which are dual to each other, are true statements.

Answer (score 0):

The dual of $1.0$ which is $0+1$, will be obtained by interchanging $AND$ to $OR$ and $1$'s to $0$'s. The result of those function needn't be same.The results will be opposite to each other $1.0=0;0+1=1$, but they are the dual form of the single function $1.0$.
For example, the dual function of $XNOR$ is $XOR$.

Answer (score -1):

In my humble opinion, it is more helpful to describe the duality relationship in terms of variables. Example:
Expression: x + x = x
Dual of expression: x * x = x
x could be 1 or 0. In all iterations, the expressions are correct.
Good Luck!

Comment: Shouldn't the dual of $ x + x = x$ be $x' \cdot x'=x'$?