# Is the duality principle of Boolean algebra always true?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I have some doubts after learning the principle of the duality of boolean algebra, which defines the dual of an expression is obtained by replacing `AND` with `OR` and `OR` with `AND`, constant `1`s by `0`s, and `0`s by `1`s.

However I encountered a problem with understanding it, which is supposing there is given that a boolean expression `A + B = 1` is true, whether or not the dual `AB = 0` is also true.

As I obtained a truth table of A + B, the given expression is true when A and B are both 1s (`1 + 1 = 1`). But I found that the dual may be wrong (`1 . 1 = 0`)

I would wonder if my concept on the principle is correct or not and the statement is false or my understanding is wrong such that the statement is true actually.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Good you look at this page: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408409/duality-principle-in-boolean-algebra

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the concept. We replace all the **variables and constants** in the expression by NOT of them. Thus dual of `A + B = 1` is `(~A)(~B) = 0` which have the same truthtable:-
$$A=0,B=0 \implies A+B=1 \space false, (\tilde{}A)(\tilde{}B)=0\space false$$
$$A=1,B=0 \implies A+B=1 \space true, (\tilde{}A)(\tilde{}B)=0\space true$$
$$A=0,B=1 \implies A+B=1 \space true, (\tilde{}A)(\tilde{}B)=0\space true$$
$$A=1,B=1 \implies A+B=1 \space true, (\tilde{}A)(\tilde{}B)=0\space true$$

Duality in Boolean Algebra ia an application of more general theory in order theorem : [Duality Law](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DualityLaw.html)