# The structure and intuition behind the logical duality principle

Tags: logic, duality-theorems

It is my first time exposure to duality, and it bothers me that the book i'm using takes this theorem for granted and only says that it is a clear fact from truth tables.

I want to know Concrete and also abstract examples of duality and also how it relates to the concepts of "And" and "Or"?

Comment: Duality in Boolean Logic or Propositional Calculus is "built in" through the semantics of the connecetives: see truth table. The t-t for $\lnot (A \lor B)$ has the same computed output of that for $(\lnot A \land \lnot B)$.

Comment: You can see [Boolean algebra : Duality principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Duality_principle) and the related post: [is-the-duality-principle-of-boolean-algebra-always-true ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2041590/is-the-duality-principle-of-boolean-algebra-always-true)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you, As I can understand You mean the Demorgan's Laws are actualy a defintion and not a result?

Comment: NO; they are a result of the basic "semantical def" via truth table. We satrt with the t-t for $\land, \lor$ and $\lnot$ and we compute the t-t for $\lnot (A \lor B)$ and $(\lnot A \land \lnot B)$ and we verify that they have the same output.

Answer (score 1):

You can nicely see the duality between And and Or in the long list of pairs of equivalence principles involving them: every time some equivalence holds involving And and Or, there is always a dual principle that also holds when systematically swapping them:

**Commutation**

$P \land Q \Leftrightarrow Q \land P$

$P \lor Q \Leftrightarrow Q \lor P$

**Association**

$P \land (Q \land R) \Leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \land R$

$P \lor (Q \lor R) \Leftrightarrow (P \lor Q) \lor R$

**DeMorgan**

$\neg(P \land Q) \Leftrightarrow \neg P \lor \neg Q$

$\neg(P \lor Q) \Leftrightarrow \neg P \land \neg Q$

**Distribution**

$P \land (Q \lor R) \Leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \lor (P \land R)$

$P \lor (Q \land R) \Leftrightarrow (P \lor Q) \land (P \lor R)$

**Absorption**

$P \land (P \lor Q) \Leftrightarrow P$

$P \lor (P \land Q) \Leftrightarrow P$

**Reduction**

$P \land (\neg P \lor Q) \Leftrightarrow P \land Q$

$P \lor (\neg P \land Q) \Leftrightarrow P \lor Q$

**Adjacency**

$P \Leftrightarrow (P \lor Q) \land (P \lor \neg Q)$

$P \Leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \lor (P \land \neg Q)$

**Consensus**

$(P \lor Q) \land (\neg Q \lor R) \land (P \lor R) \Leftrightarrow (P \lor Q) \land (\neg Q \lor R)$

$(P \land Q) \lor (\neg Q \land R) \lor (P \land R) \Leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \lor (\neg Q \land R)$