# Understanding Duality in Boolean Algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

> The dual of every true statement is true.

Though this is simple, I am having difficulties understanding this. For example, $A + A = A$ and $A . A = A$ are dual; and indeed they are both true.

But let us take the statement $A = 1$. Obviously, this is not a **true** statement ($A$ can be $0$). However, it is not false when $A = 1$.

Though the dual of $A = 1$ happens to be $A = 0$ which is false when $A = 1$. Why is that? What does it mean?

*My guess*: [Identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics)#Equality_in_algebra_and_analysis) of Boolean Algebra remain [Identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics)#Equality_in_algebra_and_analysis) after the dual operation. On the other hand, [Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics)#Equality_in_algebra_and_analysis) that where true for some subset of {0, 1} may not remain true for the **same** subset after the dual operation.

Comment: You could resolve this by dualizing the whole statement "$A = 1$ when $A = 1$", not just part of it.

Comment: See [Duality principle in boolean algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408409/duality-principle-in-boolean-algebra) and see [Duality principle (Boolean algebra)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Duality_principle).