# How to describe the duality of the quantities $ab$ and $a^2 + b^2$?

Tags: soft-question, duality-theorems

For real numbers $a, b$, the quantity $ab$ has the property that
$$ab = 0 \iff a = 0 \textrm{ or } b = 0$$
On the other hand, the quantity $a^2 + b^2$ has the property that
$$a^2 + b^2 = 0 \iff a = 0 \textrm{ and } b = 0$$

Comparing the right-hand side of the two displayed equations above, we see that they are dual to one another (in the sense of the [duality principle in Boolean algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408409/duality-principle-in-boolean-algebra)). Is there some way to describe or see this duality in the context of the expressions $ab$ and $a^2 + b^2$ themselves?  In what sense are they dual?